# How to show a loading template while logging out?

Tags: meteor, logout

There exists a `Meteor.loggingIn` but I can't find any `Meteor.loggingOut`.

I can have callbacks, but they get fired up when the user has logged out. I want to show something while he is logging out (It takes about 1-2 secs on my app).

I have been unable to find anything [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/). May be it does not exist. Has anyone ever done this type of an implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it. (And I like my method :))

```
Router.route('/logout', {
  name: 'logout',
  layoutTemplate: 'adminLayout',
  action: function(){
    this.render('loading');
    AccountsTemplates.logout(); // or Meteor.logout() depending on your package.
  }
});
```

Additionally, I have an `onLogoutHook` which redirects the user back to the homepage/login url. The neatest way I could think of. If anyone has anything better, do tell.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing 'off the shelf' as far as I know, but you could easily roll your own (provided you also create your own accounts ui).

Before calling [accountsClient.logout([callback])](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_logout) set a session variable: `Session.set('LoggingOut', true)`

Then in the callback, clear the Session variable:  `Session.set('LoggingOut', false)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably late , but meteor already has a reactive getter for this , 
`Meteor.loggingOut()` same has `Meteor.loggingIn()` , here follow this thread for more https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1331